# Create Azure Cache Programmatically

Tags: asp.net, azure, web-deployment, azure-caching, automated-deploy

I am creating an application that automate the deployment to Azure Web Sites. I was able to create Azure Web Site, database and storage programmatically but I didn't saw any library out there that can create Azure Cache programmtically. Anyone?

Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 0):

Whatever operations you perform on Windows Azure Management Portal is backed by `Windows Azure Service Management API`. I'm pretty sure that there's an API for creating and configuring caching programmatically but it has not been made public yet. I would recommend keeping an eye out on the [`REST API documentation page`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee460799.aspx). This is where you will find information about how you could create cache programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

Azure Managed Cache is in preview and hence REST API are not available for it. Also it can not be created from Portal. However, you can use Powershell commands to create it. Once created you can then manage it from azure portal itself.
Following command can be used for creating Basic Cache of 128MB.
`New-AzureManagedCache -Name YourCacheName -Location "YourLocation"`

For the detailed steps refer to - [Create Azure Managed Cache from Powershell](http://sanganakauthority.blogspot.com/2014/06/create-azure-managed-cache-service-in.html)

So you can create .ps1 file or powersehll commands string which then can be invoked from your code.
Hope this helps.